# Serial read from arduino not working properly

Tags: pi-2, serial, arduino, python-3

I am trying to read analog read from ardunio connected to my raspberry pi. Following are my raspberry pi and arduino codes.

Raspbery pi:

```
import time
import serial 
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600)
ser.flushInput()

while True:
    value = ser.readline()
    print (value)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Arduino Code:

```
int val_1,val_2;
void setup()
{
   Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    val_1 = analogRead(A0);
    val_2 = analogRead(A1);
    Serial.print(val_1);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.println(val_2);
}
```

When I try to run my python script, I get the initial analog readings from the arduino, but as the values seems to be not updating. I had to restart the script every time to read the analog pin readings.

Need to know where I am going wrong or have I missed out important factor in this.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does the answer from *oh.dae.su* help you? If so, please accept it with a click on the tick on its left side. This finishes your question and it will not pop up again year by year.

Answer (score 0):

You write with your Arduino to the serial interface continuously without any break.

On the Raspberry Pi you only read a single line every 0.5 seconds. This means your writing and reading are not in sync.

An easy remedy would be to add a delay in your Arduino code

```
delay(1000);
```

that is longer than the sleep in your Raspberry Pi code. You can drop the sleep in your Raspberry Pi code altogether.